# change listview's select threshold distance

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

It seems that the  select threshold distance  is the same  no matter how height the  listviewitem is .
When the listviewitem is small the  select threshold distance seem to be too big.

Comment: Do you mean the swipe-down-to-select gesture? I think it is important how much you have to move your finger relative to the screen size and not necessarily its relation to the size of an item - that would make it difficult to precisely select items of different sizes... Anyway - I have not seen a property that would allow you to control it and I doubt it exists. It is probably some hard-coded value or formula based on screen size and resolution.

Comment: Yes，I mean that.
If i track the event and handler it .
Can this work?

Answer (score 0):

It is not configurable.

It seems like it is best left consistent across the entire system. Even if you could hack it to modify the behavior - you would break the consistency of the interaction among the OS and different applications.